# PHP how can I execute foreach in condition

Tags: php, foreach

I'm not a developer, only know a little of programming. I'm working in a project and I need this:

1. Show data in table format only for the user logged in the system and only his own data.
2. The code I have (first part) is the one I pasted. I need from the code to execute foreach only if currentuser value is the same that 'nombre'    => $entry->meta_data['name-2']['value']

Is it possible? Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

The code:

```
function custom_form_table_front(){

global $current_user;
wp_get_current_user() ;
echo "Estás conectado/a como " . $current_user ->user_login;

ob_start();


$form_id = 15;
$entries = Forminator_API::get_entries( $form_id );

$dataFormated = [];

// Formating the data to loop easier on <table></table>

  foreach( $entries as $entry ){    
    
//Add your field values, use print_r($entry) for more information
    $dataFormated[] = [
        'nombre'    => $entry->meta_data['name-2']['value'],
        'email'   => $entry->meta_data['email-1']['value'],
        'fecha'   => $entry->meta_data['date-1']['value'],
        'destinatario'   => $entry->meta_data['name-1']['value'],
        'direccion'   => $entry->meta_data['text-1']['value'],
        'telefono'   => $entry->meta_data['phone-1']['value'],
        'comuna'   => $entry->meta_data['select-1']['value'],
        'nota'   => $entry->meta_data['textarea-1']['value'],
        'cantidad'   => $entry->meta_data['hidden-9']['value'],
        'costo'   => $entry->meta_data['hidden-10']['value'],
    ];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `$dataFormated['nombre'][$entry->meta_data['name-2']] ['value']` to a variable outside the loop, you have to come up with a logic to handle that. Then add an if condition.

```
if ($example_metanamevalueuser === $current_user) {
 foreach( $entries as $entry ){    
    $dataFormated[] = [
        'nombre'    => $entry->meta_data['name-2']['value'],
        'email'   => $entry->meta_data['email-1']['value'],
        'fecha'   => $entry->meta_data['date-1']['value'],
        'destinatario'   => $entry->meta_data['name-1']['value'],
        'direccion'   => $entry->meta_data['text-1']['value'],
        'telefono'   => $entry->meta_data['phone-1']['value'],
        'comuna'   => $entry->meta_data['select-1']['value'],
        'nota'   => $entry->meta_data['textarea-1']['value'],
        'cantidad'   => $entry->meta_data['hidden-9']['value'],
        'costo'   => $entry->meta_data['hidden-10']['value'],
    ];

 }
}
```